# JQUERY: Uncaught Error: unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I am returning a string from my server to my client and jQuery throws me the following error.

JQUERY: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Returned String is "D:/Upload/abcd@xyz.com/tracks/b8d8c86c40ee402899af1a999bbb55b1.mp3"

I am not able to figure out whats wrong with this string.

Pointers required. Thanks in advance.

Using JQuery version 1.11.1.

Apologies for that. Below is my jQueryCode. I am able to fetch the value for uploadedTrackId but it throws me an error at the next line. It does return me the path value but somehow jQuery is not able to parse it.

```
success: function (data,status) {
                        if(data['Success']!=null){
                            $('#progress-bar').load(document.URL +  ' #progress-bar');
                            $('#progress-percent').css('color',"graytext");
                            $('#progress-percent').html(data['Success']);
                            //These are the global variables containing id/path for the recently uploaded track.
                            uploadedTrackId = $(data['id']);
                            uploadedTrackPath = $(data['path']);
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your jQuery code is doing/using? :) please add the relevant code.

Comment: what happens when you console.log(data) in the console?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the returned result in jQuery? That will attempt to use it as a selector and fail as it is not a valid selector.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I am returning a JSON Object which is a key value pair. I have attached 2 screenshots. In one of the screenprints you can see i have break point setup at that point and i am evaluating the value of the data['path'] in the watch expressions and it is displaying it correctly. While in the other screen print i have done console.log on data, data['id'] and data['path'] and values are getting printed correctly. I suspect there is problem with forward slashes.

Comment: @Blkc Added a screenshot for console.log for data, data['id'], data['path']

Comment: You do not have the parse it if the call specifies JSON. "data" is already parsed and is just an object. See updated answer below. You can actually see in your screenshot (bottom right "local") that data is an Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear the be using the results as jQuery selectors. Just use them as is.

```
uploadedTrackId = data['id'];
uploadedTrackPath = data['path'];
```

You do not show the Ajax call, but data is probably already just an object with various properties. You should be able to also do the following:

```
uploadedTrackId = data.id;
uploadedTrackPath = data.path;
```